# Returning Word search results using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I would like to extract formatting information from Word documents with PowerShell. Using Word you can search formatted pieces of texts. This way Word highlights the parts satisfying the criterion (e.g. green underlined text). With this one I can find italic text in PowerShell as well:

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$myWordFile = 'C:\My\Word\File.docx'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($myWordFile)
$objDocument.Paragraphs[0].Range.Find.Font.Italic = $true
$objDocument.Paragraphs[0].Range.Find.Execute()
```

However, I'm curious about the italic text itself, a similar thing as the content of the `$matches` for `-match`.

Comment: What do yo mean by this... (However, I'm curious about the italic text itself, a similar thing as the content of the $matches for -match.)? You are working in the Word DOM, not PowerShell, the fact that you are using PowerShell interop with Word does not really change the fact that you are using DOM. So, you'd have to use Word DOM comparison, that you'd get via for example, $objWord.Selection, since you are trying to search the whole file.

Comment: @postanote Let's say I have _this in_ italics. I would like to have "this in" as a return string.

Comment: See my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do …

This is find and replace, so, ignore that replace part if that is not your end goal - it is also find words and then applying italics, but the same approach can be used to just find all italicized words.

```
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application 
$application.visible = $true 

$document = $application.documents.open("C:fsoTest.docx") 

$selection = $application.Selection 

$words = "exchange","sql" 

$matchCase = $false 
$matchWholeWord = $true 
$matchWildCards = $false 
$matchSoundsLike = $false 
$matchAllWordForms = $false 

$forward = $true 
$wrap = 1 
$format = $true 
$replace = 2 

Foreach ($word in $words) 
{ 
    $findText = $word 
    $replaceWith = $word 
    $selection.find.replacement.font.italic = $true 
    $exeRTN = $selection.find.execute($findText,$matchCase, 
    $matchWholeWord,$matchWIldCards,$matchSoundsLike, 
    $matchAllWordForms,$forward,$wrap,$format,$replaceWith, 
    $replace) 
}
```

… as documented here:

[Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Italicize Specific Words in a Microsoft Word Document?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/12/28/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-italicize-specific-words-in-a-microsoft-word-document)

Comment: It is not totally clear for me, how do I have a variable as in my example, which has a string value of "this in"